# Applescript Selecting Specific Inbox in Apple Mail

Tags: email, applescript, inbox

I am new to Applescript and I am running into an issue. I have multiple folder in my Mail "Inbox". However, I would like to just select one of these inboxes to run the script on it.

Here is what I have. However, I cannot seem to find the Inbox for the Gmail account.

Any ideas?

```
    set _ago to (current date) - days
    set _inbox to "Inbox:Gmail"

    tell application "Mail"
        move (messages of _inbox whose read status is false and date received comes before _ago) to mailbox "Gmail - Unread"
        move (messages of _inbox whose date received comes before _ago) to mailbox "Gmail - Archive"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems, although I haven't seen this *documented* anywhere, that inboxes are always mailboxes named "INBOX" (case matters).  Thus, the following is what I do [when I need to access an account-specific inbox](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/script-that-outputs-number-of-emails-in-mail-app-inbox/7902#7902):

```
set _inbox to mailbox "INBOX" of account "Gmail"
```

It's the same way you'd access any mailbox, you just use this particular name.  Note also that you might need to use the `mailbox "Unread" of account "Gmail"` form in your `move` statements as well, but I'm not sure; you'd need to test this.

Comment: This solved my problem, which was the same thing as OP's. Thank you. OP should have marked it as the answer.